# Can you tell a MutationObserver to only listen to specific inputs, e.g. to select an entire group of choices in a pickerInput?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, mutation-observers

This is inspired by and a follow up to [Is there a way to select an entire group of choices on a pickerInput from shinyWidgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908249/is-there-a-way-to-select-an-entire-group-of-choices-on-a-pickerinput-from-shinyw)

The selected answer works wonderfully for a single `pickerInput`, but problems arise as soon as a second ("later") one is in the same app. For example, consider a setup with two `pickerInput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

js <- HTML("
$(function() {
  let observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  function clickHandler(evt) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('group_select', $(this).children('span').text(),{priority: \"event\"});
  }

  function callback(mutations) {
    for (let mutation of mutations) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        $('.dropdown-header').on('click', clickHandler).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        
      }
    }
  }

  let options = {
    childList: true,
  };

  observer.observe($('.inner')[0], options);
})
")

choices <- list("A" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), "B" = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10), "C" = c(11,12,13,14,15))

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(js)),
    pickerInput("test", choices = choices, multiple = TRUE,options = list('actions-box' = TRUE)),
    textOutput("testOutput"),
    pickerInput("test_2", choices = choices, multiple = TRUE,options = list('actions-box' = TRUE)),
    textOutput("testOutput_2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$testOutput <- renderText({paste(input$test)})
    output$testOutput_2 <- renderText({paste(input$test_2)})
    
    observeEvent(input$group_select, {
        req(input$group_select)
        if(all(choices[[input$group_select]] %in% input$test_2)){
            sel <- input$test_2[!(input$test_2 %in% choices[[input$group_select]])]
        }else{
            sel <- union(input$test_2, choices[[input$group_select]])
        }
        updatePickerInput(session, "test_2", selected = sel)
    }) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With this, clicking on a group in the first `pickerInput` updates the second one while clicking on a group in the second one does nothing. How do I tell the `MutationObserver` to listen for and only for mutations in the second `pickerInput`?

In my actual usecase, I have two different `pickerInput` on two different tabs (from `shinydashboard`) that I'd like to have this functionality for. So maybe it is enough to tell the `MutationObserver` on which tab to look? (See [How do I use shinyjs to identify if tab is active in shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163287/how-do-i-use-shinyjs-to-identify-if-tab-is-active-in-shiny) , but being a JS beginner, I am not really sure how I can use this).

**UPDATE**

I've managed to get ever so slightly closer in my usecase by adding `req(input$sidebar == "tab_name")` to the `observeEvent` parts. Now they both update the correct `pickerInput`, but for the second one, the functionality works only once after every time I've clicked on a group header in the first `pickerInput`.

So, still not there. I'm trying to get a reproducible example using tabs from `shinydashboard`, but for some reason as soon as I introduce them to the MWE, the whole `mutationObserver` stops working altogether.

**UPDATE 2**

@thothal's answer worked. I rewrote the `observeEvent` part to the following to get the same functionality:

```
observeEvent(input$group_select, {
    req(input$group_select)
    if(all(choices[[input$group_select[[1]]]] %in% input[[names(input$group_select)]])){
      sel <- input[[names(input$group_select)]][!(input[[names(input$group_select)]] %in% choices[[input$group_select[[1]]]])]
    }else{
      sel <- union(input[[names(input$group_select)]],choices[[input$group_select[[1]]]])
    }
    updatePickerInput(session,names(input$group_select),selected = sel)
  })
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of the original answer here. Actually, you need to adapt the code as follows:

1. Your `clickHandler` should return the id of the clicked `pickerInput` such that `Shiny` can know which `pickerInput` to update.
2. Your `observer` must listen on a different node. The class `.inner` worked well with `fluidPage` layouts as apparently the `.inner` class is existing when the DOM is loaded, but **not** with `shinydashboard` (I guess that the parts are not yet loaded when the JS fires). The easiest is to listen to `body` (which will be there for sure), but it may be an expensive operation, b/c a narrower target may require less resources.

Having said that, a working solution looks like this (*N.B.* You can add as many `pickerInputs` and the handler should work as expected):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(purrr)

js <- HTML("
$(function() {
  let observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  function clickHandler(evt) {
    let id = $(this).parents('.bootstrap-select').children('select').attr('id');
    let res = {};
    res[id] = $(this).children('span').text();
    Shiny.setInputValue('group_select', res);
  }

  function callback(mutations) {
    for (let mutation of mutations) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        $('.dropdown-header').on('click', clickHandler).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        
      }
    }
  }

  let options = {
    childList: true,
  };

  observer.observe($('body')[0], options);
})
")

choices <- list("A" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), "B" = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(),
   dashboardSidebar(pickerInput("test1", choices = choices, multiple = TRUE),
                     pickerInput("test2", choices = choices, multiple = TRUE)),
   dashboardBody(tags$head(tags$script(js)),
                 verbatimTextOutput("testOutput")),
   title = "Multipicker"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$testOutput <- renderPrint({
      input$group_select
   })
   
   observeEvent(input$group_select, {
      req(input$group_select)
      iwalk(input$group_select, ~ updatePickerInput(session, .y, selected = choices[[.x]]))
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

### Update

In order to allow for deselecting upon second click and keeping the selection persistent, we have to make 2 changes:

1. Tell JS to send each click (and not only new clicks):

```js
function clickHandler(evt) {
    let id = $(this).parents('.bootstrap-select').children('select').attr('id');
    let res = {};
    res[id] = $(this).children('span').text();
    Shiny.setInputValue('group_select', res, {priority: 'event'}); // change here
}
```

2. Adapt the `observer`

```r
observeEvent(input$group_select, {
   req(input$group_select)
   iwalk(input$group_select, function(.x, .y) {
      sel <- input[[.y]]
      new <- choices[[.x]]
      if (length(intersect(sel, new))) {
         ## unselect already selected items
         sel <- setdiff(sel, new)
      } else {
         sel <- union(sel, new)
      }
      updatePickerInput(session, .y, selected = sel)
      })
})
```

The behaviour is now that a click will add all the sub-items if (and only if) none of the sub items is already selected. If there is at least one sub-item selected all subitems are deselected. Finally, selections pile up. That is previous selections are not discarded but a new selection is added to the previous.

Comment: Why not simply do `$(body).on("click", ".dropdown-header", clickHandler)`, instead of using a mutation observer?

Comment: [Look to the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908249/is-there-a-way-to-select-an-entire-group-of-choices-on-a-pickerinput-from-shinyw).

Comment: Thank you very much, the JS changes do the trick. One question: If I want to customize the `updatePickerInput`, how do I access the id inside the `observeEvent`? With `input$group_select` I seem to only get the group header name.

Comment: `input$group_select` does return a list, whose name equals the `pickerInput` id and the value corresponds to the group header name. Thus, `names(input$group_select)` will give you the id, and `input$group_select` will give you the group header name.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me out a lot. It works now, the only quirk is that I cannot click on the same group header twice in a row, I need to click on another one before choosing the same one again (so e.g. no quick unselect after a misclick select).

Comment: Well, change to `Shiny.setInputValue('group_select', res, {priority: 'event'})`. Then each click will be reported to shiny and you can react accordingly. Will add an update.